# LED light strip vs. incandescent light bulb power consumption ambiguousness

Tags: power, led

Formula for power is:

```
P = I * U
```

or Power (Watt) equals Current (Ampere) * Voltage (Volt).

For my LED strip (5 m in length), it says power consumption is 18 Watts at 12 V. That means, (I=P/U) it draws 1.5 Amps.

For my mains power incandescent light bulb consumption is:  120W / 220V. It draws 0.54 Amps.

Where's the logic in that? It means that three power hungry inefficient light bulbs will draw less current then one LED strip, simply because they run on higher voltage?  What am I missing?

Comment: What happened to three 120W bulbs : 3 * 120 = 360W...

Comment: *Where's the logic in that?* Why isn't this logical. You're appear to conclude that more current always means more power. So my device uses 1000 A at only 0.01 V. Does it consume more power than your led strip or lightbulbs?

Comment: I'm looking from viewpoint of efficiency. We pay for Amp/Hours. It appears that devices running on higher voltages are more efficient then devices running on lower voltages. Luminosity is proportionate to Watts (Power).

Comment: @MitjaGustin You pay for Ah at particular voltage, which means you pay for Wh.

Comment: What you are missing is that Power depends on voltage and current, as you have shown in your formula. The in UK we pay for electricity in kWh, which is just the amp hours, multiplied by the voltage is delivered in (to put it into Watts) multiplied by 1000 (as it's killo-Watt hours)

Answer (score 6):

What you are missing is that you are not paying for the current at 12V. You are paying for the power drawn from the mains. If the LED strip is powered by a PSU which is 80% efficient, then it will draw 18/0.8 = 22.5 W from the mains, which is 0.102 Amps at 220V. This is what you should compare to your 0.54 Amps for the incandescent lamp.

Answer (score -1):

Current is not the same as power

Power = Amps x Volts